# Multi-page one-column abstract in a two-column document

Tags: page-breaking, two-column, abstract

I'm making a two-column document, but I need a one-column abstract. The code:

```
\twocolumn[
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
...
\end{abstract}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
```

doesn't work, because the abstract is longer enough to use two pages and page don't break. I also tried making a one-column document and used the multicol environment only for the document "text" (not the abstract), but then i had problems with the figure environment.

So, how can I make a one-column abstract?

Comment: Is there any text environment with automatic page break? If that doesn't exist, can I write it?

Comment: That's not the best way of using the concept of *Abstract* if it is more than one page. I would go with *Summary* or something similar.

Comment: actualy the abstract is not that long, but with the title, the abstract needs to be splited into 2 pages.

Comment: i'm not sure this is a duplicate.  although it's not an ideal situation, this abstract must break to a second page.  so the approach taken depends (1) on the document class that is/must be used, and (2) whether or not there will be footnotes in the remainder of the document -- the suggested `multicol` in one answer to the question cited by @PeterGrill will place footnotes across the whole page, not in the column from which the footnote is called.

Comment: How can I tell whoever closed this post that this post is not a duplicate, since I say that the code in the other post doesn't work for me? Thanks

Comment: I agree it is not a duplicate and it might get re-open soon ;) I as well have a solution, but I have to re-code it a bit, which will take a while.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can copy the following code as a file `long2.sty`, place it in your document folder, and then use it as shown below:

```
%%
%% This is file `long2.sty'.
%%
%% Author: Tomas "tohecz" Hejda <tohecz@gmail.com>
%%
%% Licenced under LaTeX-Project Public License version 1.3 or newer.
%% 
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{long2}[2012/08/19 v0.1 long2: breakable one-column preamble in a two-column document]

\newlength\longtwo@top
\newlength\longtwo@bottom

\newsavebox\longtwo@box
\def\longtwo@repeat{%
    \longtwo@column[{\@twocolumnfalse
    \ifdim\ht\longtwo@box>1.00\textheight%1
      \begingroup
      \vbadness10000
      \setbox0\vsplit\longtwo@box to 1.00\textheight%1
      \setbox1\vbox{\unvbox\longtwo@box}
      \global\setbox\longtwo@box\vbox{\unvbox1}
      \setbox2\vbox to \textheight{%
        \unvbox0
      }
      \ht2=0.9\textheight
      \box2
      \endgroup
    \else
      \ifdim\ht\longtwo@box>0.84\textheight
        \global\let\longtwo@repeat\clearpage
      \else
        \global\let\longtwo@repeat\relax
      \fi
      \unvbox\longtwo@box
      \vspace{15pt plus 15pt}
    \fi
    }]%
  \longtwo@repeat
}

\long\def\longtwo@[#1]{%
  \begingroup
    \let\longtwo@column\twocolumn
    \let\longtwo@mkttl\maketitle
    \def\maketitle{
      \begingroup
      \let\newpage\relax
      \longtwo@mkttl
      \endgroup
    }
    \longtwo@column[{\@twocolumnfalse
    \global\setbox\longtwo@box\vbox{#1}%
    \ifdim\ht\longtwo@box>\textheight
      \begingroup
      \vbadness10000
      \setbox0\vsplit\longtwo@box to 1.00\textheight%1
      \setbox1\vbox{\unvbox\longtwo@box}%
      \global\setbox\longtwo@box\vbox{\unvbox1}%
      \setbox2\vbox to \textheight{%
        \unvbox0
      }
      \ht2=0.9\textheight
      \box2
      \endgroup
    \else
      \ifdim\ht\longtwo@box>0.87\textheight
        \global\let\longtwo@repeat\clearpage
      \else
        \global\let\longtwo@repeat\relax
      \fi
      \unvbox\longtwo@box
    \fi
    }]%
    \longtwo@repeat
  \endgroup
}

\def\longtwocolumn{\@ifnextchar[\longtwo@\twocolumn}

\endinput
%%
%% End of file `long2.sty'.
%%
```

The document can then look like this (package `lipsum` and command `\lipsum[x-y]` are only used to produce some dummy text):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{long2}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parskip0pt plus 8pt

\title{My title}
\author{My the first}

\begin{document}

\longtwocolumn[{
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{abstract}
\lipsum[9-15]
}]

\lipsum[16-25]

\end{document}
```

PS: I'm considering making it a package (after I add some features), that's why I posted a complete package file `;)`

PPS: Brief introduction of the idea: We store the whole one-column part in a box, then we check whether the box is larger than a page. If yes, we `\vsplit` it, output the first part, and call `\longtwo@repeat` on the rest, which does the same again.

Comment: Too complex, I don't get it... and I can't make it work.

Comment: Well, what does it mean "can't make it work"? If you save the first code as `long2.sty` and the second one as `test.tex`, it does not compile? And yes, it is complex, because you are asking for a complicated thing.

Comment: @Agustin: For an initial test, place the `long2.sty` in the same directory where you have the example above and try. If it does not work, please detail the result and provide the error message you get.

Comment: It worked very good. It makes some vspaces to print diferent, but nothing I can not fix. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Where did you leaned all that? If it is a book, which one? I wanna learn too but i dont find any book or manual.

Comment: There are some books of course, but I cannot help you, I'm a complete self-learner with these tricks. I only use a reference of eTeX commands: http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html#p-ai And you really need `\tracingmacros=1` (see the reference linked for `\tracing...` commands explained).

Answer (score 4):

New solution, use `\afterpage` to insert the twocolumn switch after the page break, butting the end of the abstract into its optional argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\let\xaddboxcontents\addboxcontents
\def\zzz#1\end#2{\end{abstract}\twocolumn[\unvbox\csname AP@partial\endcsname\par\small\quotation#1\endquotation]}
\def\addboxcontents#1{\aftergroup\zzz}
\author{me}
\date{today}
\title{test}
\def\b{abstract stuff }\def\c{\b\b\b. }\def\d{One \c. Two three \c. Four five six\c\c.\par}\def\e{\d\d\d\d\d}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\afterpage{\clearpage}
\begin{abstract}
\e\e\e\e
\end{abstract}


\def\b{main body text }
\e\e\e\e\e

\end{document}
```

---

Original (simpler!) solution:

Switch to one column for the title and abstract then back to two

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\author{me}
\date{today}
\title{test}
\def\b{abstract stuff }\def\c{\b\b\b. }\def\d{One \c. Two three \c. Four five six\c\c.\par}\def\e{\d\d\d\d\d}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\e\e\e\e
\end{abstract}
\twocolumn

\def\b{main body text }
\e\e\e\e\e

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah, that works great, but it start a new page and I'm not supposed to do that, actualy I can't do it because it is for a job. Is there any option that tells the \twocolumn command not to start a new page? Thanks

Comment: No the standard two column system requires a page break. multicol does not, but as you noted in the question that has other restrictions. you may be able to use afterpage, I'll have a think

Comment: afterpage version added