# (Entire) Table of Contents won't appear on separate page

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx

So I'm trying to get my Table of Contents to appear on a separate page. I've added the `\newpage` tags above and below `.toc`, but for some reason it's having no effect. I also tried `\clearpage`, but that had no effect either. I'm not very experienced with either LaTeX or LyX and am wondering if I'm just *totally* missing something here?

[image: TOC in LyX]

```
    #LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 2cm
\topmargin 2cm
\rightmargin 2cm
\bottommargin 2cm
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
twocolumn[
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Title

\series bold
Title
\end_layout

\begin_layout Author
Author Name
\end_layout

\begin_layout Date
Date
\end_layout

\begin_layout Section*
\begin_inset CommandInset line
LatexCommand rule
offset "0.5ex"
width "100text%"
height "1pt"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Abstract
Abstract.

\end_layout

\begin_layout Section*
\begin_inset CommandInset line
LatexCommand rule
offset "0.5ex"
width "100text%"
height "1pt"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Newpage newpage
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset toc
LatexCommand tableofcontents

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Newpage newpage
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
end{@twocolumnfalse}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

]
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
sloppy
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Section

\noun on
Introduction
\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
Materials
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsection
Site 959
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsubsection
Site, setting and lithology description of Hole 959 A
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsubsection
Age model of Hole 959 A
\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
Methods
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsection
TEX
\begin_inset script subscript

\begin_layout Plain Layout
86
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsubsection
TEX
\begin_inset script subscript

\begin_layout Plain Layout
86
\end_layout

\end_inset

 validity indicators
\end_layout

\begin_layout Paragraph
BIT Index
\end_layout

\begin_layout Paragraph
Methane Index
\end_layout

\begin_layout Paragraph
Additional GDGT distributions 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsection
Palynological analysis
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsubsection
Dinoflagellate cysts
\end_layout

\begin_layout Paragraph
Processing and analyses
\end_layout

\begin_layout Paragraph
Grouping of taxa 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsubsection
Palynomorphs 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsection
Statistical analysis
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsubsection
Shannon index
\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
Results
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsection
Palynology
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsubsection
Diversity and evenness
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsection
Palaeothermometry
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsubsection
Reliability of TEX
\begin_inset script subscript

\begin_layout Plain Layout
86
\end_layout

\end_inset

 data
\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
Discussion
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsection
The Eocene-Oligocene Transition
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsection
Palaeoenvironment
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsubsection
Regional oceanographic setting 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsubsection
Sea-level
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsubsection
Temperature 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Paragraph
Regional Temperature
\end_layout

\begin_layout Paragraph
Global Temperature 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsubsection
Possible forcing mechanisms of the EOT
\end_layout

\begin_layout Paragraph
Southern Ocean Gateway opening
\end_layout

\begin_layout Paragraph
CO
\begin_inset script subscript

\begin_layout Plain Layout
2
\end_layout

\end_inset

 decline
\end_layout

\begin_layout Paragraph
Comparison to climate model outputs
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subsection
Conclusion
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a MWE (minimal (not-)working example file) as documented in the Lyx wiki.

Comment: Try clear double page too. Or post a minimal example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer of sorts:

From my understanding using `\twocolumn[ ]` and `\begin{@twocolumnfalse} ... \end{@twocolumnfalse}` does not allow for automatic or manual page breaking. So, my suggestion is to have two separate `\twocolumn[ ]` environments (note: you don't need to have new pages anymore).

However, the main problem you will run into is if your table of contents is too long it will **not** automatically page break for you. You may need this solution if your table of contents extends over one page: [Multi-page one-column abstract in a two-column document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74433/multi-page-one-column-abstract-in-a-two-column-document)

[image]